# JSON data parsing in Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart, mobile, mobile-application

I have JSON data from API, and I want to parse it by classes. But I have one problem. In first video, questions is equal to null, but in another videos it isn't null. I don't understand how to parse it.

```
[{type: MAIN, video: {id: firstIdStr, url: firstURLStr, thumbnail: firstThumbmainURLStr, duration: 4363}, question: null}, {type: ANSWER_FOR_INTERVIEW, video: {id: secondIdStr, url: secondURLStr, thumbnail: secondThumbmainURLStr, duration: 4123}, question: {id:quiestioId, category:questionCategory, text:questionText}, {type: ANSWER_FOR_INTERVIEW, video: {id: thirdIdStr, url: thirdURLStr, thumbnail: thirdThumbmainURLStr, duration: 4123}, question: {id:quiestioId, category:questionCategory, text:questionText}}]
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the answer

```
class Question {
  Question({
    this.category,
    this.id,
    this.text,
  });

  String category;
  String id;
  String text;

  factory Question.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => json == null
      ? null
      : Question(
          category: json["category"],
          id: json["id"],
          text: json["text"],
        );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "category": category != null ? category : "",
        "id": id != null ? id : "",
        "text": text != null ? text : "",
      };
}
```